# Spring Entity OneToMany Ignore Self

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, entity

Currently, I have the following relationship between two entities:

```
@Entity
public class Pokemon {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "trainer_id")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("pokemons")
    private Trainer trainer;
}
```

and also:

```
@Entity
public class Trainer {
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
     mappedBy = "trainer")
    private Set<Pokemon> pokemons = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Everything is fine when updating the entities. However, when I attempt to retrieve all trainers, it includes the trainer within the pokemon, which I don't want. Observe:

GET ALL POKEMON (all is fine):

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "squirtle",
    "type": "water",
    "trainer": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Ash Ketchum",
        "level": 1
    }
}
```

GET ALL TRAINERS:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Ash Ketchum",
    "level": 1,
    "pokemons": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "squirtle",
            "type": "water",
            "trainer": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Ash Ketchum",
                "level": 1
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Notice how the trainer class is returned within each pokemon inside of the the pokemons set? I'd prefer not to return that, since I already have access to that information. Is there anyway I can tell the entity not to return its own info from the Pokemon class? If it helps, my retrieval query looks like this:

```
public List<Trainer> getAllTrainers() {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    List<Trainer> trainer = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM
    Trainer", Trainer.class).getResultList();
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    return trainer;
}
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: You have FetchType.EAGER - try with LAZY

Comment: I tried that but I get "failed to lazily initalize a collection of role" error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, I was able to achieve my goal by telling my Trainer class to ignore the trainer property in the Pokemon object via @JsonIgnoreProperties

```
@Entity
public class Trainer implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "trainer")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "trainer")
    private Set<Pokemon> pokemons = new HashSet<>();
```